# Python Tkinter change app menu command works at root but not when inside a frame class

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to follow along with setting up an app that will have multiple windows I stack and then just bring to front the one that gets called. It's based on this series of videos

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0gaXfM1UN0&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk&index=2

I want to change the app name and the standard File and Help menus when it runs on Mac systems.

When I use this structure it all works:

```
if platform == 'darwin':
    from Foundation import NSBundle
       bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    if bundle:
        info = bundle.localizedInfoDictionary() or bundle.infoDictionary()
        if info and info['CFBundleName'] == 'Python':
            info['CFBundleName'] = "LambTracker"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title ("LambTracker")
root.geometry("1200x900")
root.minsize(1000, 750)
mainmenu = tk.Menu(root)
appmenu = tk.Menu(mainmenu, name='apple')
mainmenu.add_cascade(menu=appmenu)
appmenu.add_command(label='About LambTracker', command=aboutlambtracker)
appmenu.add_separator()
root['menu'] = mainmenu
fileMenu = tk.Menu(mainmenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open Database", command=donothing)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New Database", command=donothing)
helpMenu = tk.Menu(mainmenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Help", command=donothing)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Release Notes", command=donothing)
helpMenu.add_command(label="GitLab Source Code", command=donothing)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Contact Us", command=donothing)

root.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

but if I try to put that inside a class and change the root to self I get an error  unknown option "-menu" I don't understand why it's available when the target is root but not when the target is self.

```
class LambTrackerApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        mainmenu = tk.Menu(self)
        appMenu = tk.Menu(mainmenu, name='apple')
        mainmenu.add_cascade(menu=appMenu)
        appMenu.add_command(label='About LambTracker', command=aboutlambtracker)
        appMenu.add_separator()
        self['menu'] = mainmenu
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(mainmenu)
        mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open Database", command=donothing)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="New Database", command=donothing)
        helpMenu = tk.Menu(mainmenu)
        helpMenu.add_command(label="Help", command=donothing)
        helpMenu.add_command(label="Release Notes", command= donothing)
        helpMenu.add_command(label="GitLab Source Code", command=donothing)
        helpMenu.add_command(label="Contact Us", command=donothing)
app = LambTrackerApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I'm writing in Python 3.7

Comment: You can't associate menus with frames, only the root window and toplevel windows.

Comment: But the menu I'm trying to modify isn't attached to any tkinter window or frame. It's the one that is always at the top of any app in OS X. 

Is there a way to modify that menubar and still have a way to easily change the user window? 

I've got multiple screens or windows with different options I need to have the user see and interact with based on selecting items in the top main application window.

Comment: _"But the menu I'm trying to modify isn't attached to any tkinter window or frame."_ - yes it is: `self['menu'] = mainmenu` `self` is a frame. Frames don't have menus, hence the "unknown option" message.

Comment: I'm not explaining the problem properly, sorry.  If I put the code to change the app name and custom file and help menus in the root window, how then do I implement multiple frames in a stack so I can easily pop them to the top to show or hide them for the user t interact with? Similar to how Android Java Activities each have their own window and calling an activity changes the window. My python app is desktop adjunct to existing Android tablet app for sheep flock management.